# What is wrong with the java script settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

after searching for solution to hide notificationBar without a button oncomplete XX.hide()

I find a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function() {
          bar.show();
          setTimeout("bar.hide()",5000);
           });
         </script>
```

it works perfecttly when I place this code after `</p:notificationBar>`

But My problem is that I want to display notification after executing my methode and after 5 seconds, hide this component.
But I do not haw I call this javascrpit on `oncomplete` so I copy two line this is my code

```
<p:commandButton value="Run" action="#{optionBean.updateParametre()}" oncomplete="bar.show(),setTimeout(bar.hide(),50000);" update="panel"/>
    <p:notificationBar position="bottom" effect="fade" widgetVar="bar"  > 
    <f:facet name="close">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/image/closebar.png" />  
        </f:facet>  
    <h:outputText value="Parametre Enregistre !" style="color:#FFCC00;font-size:36px;" />  
</p:notificationBar>
```

the problem is that notifationBar disappear quickly whatever the fixed time !!!why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtle difference in the way you're calling setTimeout that's making all the difference.

Compare

- `setTimeout("bar.hide()",5000);`
- `setTimeout(bar.hide(),50000)`

Besides the order of magnitude difference, `bar.hide()` is quoted on the top and is *not* quoted on the bottom. When you [pass string literals to setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals), they're `eval`'d when the timeout happens.

In the second instance, `bar.hide()` is unquoted. What's happening is that `bar.hide()` is being called immediately when the timeout is created, and the return value of the `hide` function is being called when the timeout happens.

The easiest way to fix this would be to modify your oncomplete attribute to

`oncomplete="bar.show(),setTimeout('bar.hide()',50000);"`

There is a better way. jQuery can chain effects like this using [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), but someone else already gave that answer so I won't repeat it here.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  bar.show();
  setTimeout(function(){ bar.hide(); },5000);
});
```

Another way you can achieve that is to add a toggle with a slow fade out, I think 5s is a slow time to look at the notification.

Comment: thanyou @Omar I try also oncomplete="bar.show();setTimeout(function(){ bar.hide(); },9000);"                                                          Haw can I call this function from autocomplete !!!won't to test him from on complete

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function() {
           bar.show().delay(50000).hide();
           });
         </script>  it is allways the same 5000,550000000,11111000 it is the same waiting time

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
jQuery(function(){

     bar.show().delay(5000).hide();

});
```